# shasum -a 256 on dmg file returns nothing

Tags: macos, command-line

I am getting no results when I check this freshly downloaded file from TDAmeritrade.

I have searched for an answer to this but no joy.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

```
Edges-MacBook-Pro:Downloads edge$ shasum -a 256 thinkorswim.installer.dmg
shasum: thinkorswim.installer.dmg:  
Edges-MacBook-Pro:Downloads edge$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command

```
$ shasum -a 256 /path/to/file
```

will return the name of the file if it can't find it. E.g.

```
$ shasum -a 256 nofilehere
shasum: nofilehere:
```

Otherwise, it will display the hash value and the name of the file:

```
$ shasum -a 256 theFile
d7f6436a313e17b01af27cf7582f8aa0149554c20d3257133cf7680e25fc287b theFile
```

Check where you downloaded the file. If it is in the Download directory, then this will work:

```
$ shasum -a 256 ~/Downloads/thinkorswim.installer.dmg
```

If shasum is not displaying the hash value, then either the file isn't where you specified or the file name is wrong.

Comment: Well, do I feel silly.  I "interpreted" an underscore as a "." !  Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh yeah - common mistake everyone of us makes. I forgot about the possibility of the file name being wrong. Updated answer.

Comment: Dragging the file into the window after typing the command is an excellent way to help with escaping odd characters and path issues @25thfret thanks for asking, I learned something new here, too